# SharePoint 2010 custom publishing page not displaying as expected in Edit Mode

Tags: publishing-site

I have a SharePoint 2010 publishing site with all publishing features enabled.  If I create an OOTB article page, my edit page experience looks like this:

[image: article page in edit mode shows field outlines]

However, when I edit my custom publishing page, my experience looks like this:

[image: custom publishing page missing field outlines]

I expected my custom publishing page layouts to behave like the article page where editing fields were outlined with the field name in the "tab".  Is this not the case or am I missing a bit of configuration?

To create my site columns, I used the following XML in a Powershell call to $rootWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml():

```
"<Field Type=`"HTML`" RichText=`"TRUE`" RichTextMode=`"ThemeHtml`" 
                          Name=`"$name`"
                          Description=`"$desc`" 
                          DisplayName=`"$disp`" 
                          StaticName=`"$stat`" 
                          Group=`"OperMan`"
                          Hidden=`"FALSE`"
                          Required=`"FALSE`"
                          Sealed=`"FALSE`"
                          ShowInDisplayForm=`"TRUE`"
                          ShowInEditForm=`"TRUE`"
                          ShowInListSettings=`"TRUE`"
                          ShowInNewForm=`"TRUE`"></Field>"
```

To create my custom content types, I used the parent type "Page".

I then created corresponding custom page layouts for my custom content types.

Am I confused about how this is supposed to work or am I missing something?

I appreciate your help in advance!

Thanks...janice

Comment: Ahhh...good point.  I will move it.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out a solution.  Not sure if it is the correct one.  In SPD, I created a new page layout based on my custom content type.  Then, I borrowed the styling from one of the article page layouts.  I used PageFromDocLayout.aspx but removed the UIVersion 3 code and the roll-up image.  Worked nicely.  Now, my custom page layouts have the nicer editing experience.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turned out that stupidly enough the PageImage field control makes the page include some extra css which render the field borders and titles. I had removed the control since my publishing pages didn't need a specific image, any image would be included using the rich text field. I added the field on the page again in a hidden (display:none;) div and al my fields rendered again in edit mode :-S.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the following CSS where .ms-formfieldlabelcontainer and .ms-formfieldvaluecontainer are the classes you can override to have the look and feel you need

```
.ms-formfieldlabelcontainer{margin-bottom:0;margin-left:4px;margin-right:4px;margin-top:4px}
.ms-formfieldvaluecontainer{border:1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom:4px;margin-left:4px;margin-right:4px;padding:5px}
```